# Stock Price Alert Application Using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am currently working on my Big Data class project, focusing on building a stock price alerting app (via email) using Spark Streaming and Kafka.

**Sample stock trading data**

```
stockName,tradeType,price,quantity,timestamp 
MQG,SELL,940.22,25,2023-11-06 00:01:00.000
```

**My kafka provider**:

```
def send_data():
    producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'})
    topic = "stream-price"
    df = pd.read_csv('../../data/stock_trading_data.csv')

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        dict_stock = json.dumps(row.to_dict()).encode('utf-8')
        try:
            producer.produce(topic, value=dict_stock)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error producing message: {e}")

        sleep_time = 10  # each 30 seconds
        sleep(sleep_time)

    producer.flush()
    producer.close()
```

In my Spark Structured Streaming app, I read from two streams: one for Kafka stock data and another for user configurations.
**Stock data stream**

```
data_stream = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", topic_streaming) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()
data_json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("stockName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("tradeType", StringType(), True),
    StructField("price", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("quantity", LongType(), True),
    StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
])

data_stream = data_stream.selectExpr("cast(value as string) as value")
data_stream = data_stream.withColumn("value", from_json(
    data_stream["value"], data_json_schema)).select("value.*")
data_stream = data_stream.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(
    data_stream["timestamp"], "HH:mm:ss"))
```

**Requirements stream**

```
require_stream = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9090) \
    .load()
require_json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("stockNameRule", StringType()),
    StructField("tradeTypeRule", StringType(), True),
    StructField("priceRule", DoubleType()),
    StructField("quantityRule", LongType(), True),
])

require_stream = require_stream \
    .select(from_json("value", configs_json_schema).alias("data")) \
    .select("data.*")
```

To alert users when stock price data meets requirements, I plan to use a **stream-stream join with a filter**:

```
join_stream = data_stream.join(
    configs_stream,
    expr("""
         stockName = stockNameRule AND
         price >= priceRule
         """)
join_stream = df_with_stateful \
     .writeStream \
     .foreach(process_row) \ # send email func
     .start()
```

** But I got 2 problems

1. How can I send an email for just the **last stock data that meets the last requirements**? In other words, just send one neccessary email when thelast data meets the last requirements , not for all read stream.
2. How can I handle situations where newer stock prices arrive later than older ones?
   I've read about window and watermark, but I'm unsure how to use them effectively. Can you provide some guidance or solutions?

Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: Spark can write to Kafka as well, btw, you didn't need to write a separate producer. Otherwise, Spark can read CSV files, so Kafka seems irrelevant here. And you've not shown `process_row`, but it has no "memory" to know if you've seen an earlier/higher price, so you need some external storage to track this, outside of Spark or Kafka

Comment: @OneCricketeer my teacher wants us to demo with Kafka. I think  process_row is only func to send email with input is an new row when data meet requirements. To send email with only the the last "meet" between two stream, I think my teacher want us to spark's features like window, waterMark 
I mean that when the first data stream has two rows :  
price: 10, timestamp: 10:01 
price: 20, timestamp: 10:05
When requirements change to "price > 5", the app just send email for the last price (20)

Comment: Spark /kafka have no email libraries... Python does. Therefore, windowing doesn't help "send emails". You need something else to scan each window that's being built, and something else to track  the max value of every window ever built to prevent ones where newer max window price (in terms of time) could be less than previous ones (assuming you're alerting on overall greatest price).. If the requirements change while the data is being consumed, then you'll also need persistent storage / history tracking rather than only windowing